# How to query MongoDB for column1 > column2 * 5?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to get records with column1 > (column2 * 5)?
I've tried this but nothing returned:

```
db.getCollection('rss').find({'duplicates': {$gt: 'total_count' * 5}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#examples)** operator where you can pass in a JavaScript expression:

```
db.getCollection('rss').find({ "$where": "this.duplicates > (this.total_count * 5)" }) 
// sama as db.getCollection('rss').find("this.duplicates > (this.total_count * 5)")
```

or use the aggregation framework with the **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#_S_cmp)** operator which is far more effecient than the above because using **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#examples)** alone will require Mongo to do a collection scan where each document has to be converted from BSON to a JavaScript object and then run through the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#examples)** expression. Indexes cannot be used to satisfy a **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#examples)** expression either, hence performance is greatly reduced and queries are much slower.

---

Using the **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#_S_cmp)** operator will give you much better performance as it compares two values and returns

- -1 if the first value is less than the second.
- 1 if the first value is greater than the second.
- 0 if the two values are equivalent.

So your final query would look like:

```
db.getCollection('rss').aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            // Project other fields as required
            "duplicates": 1,
            "total_count": 1,
            "isGreater": {
                "$cmp": [
                    "$duplicates", 
                    { "$multiply": [ "$total_count", 5 ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "isGreater": 1 } } 
])
```